# Why are asymptotically flat two-sided black holes entangled?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, black-holes, quantum-entanglement, ads-cft

So I've been reading through Maldacena and Susskind's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0533) on ER = EPR, and I ran into a question. They start by analyzing the AdS eternal black hole,

[image]

which has a thermofield double description
$$|\psi\rangle\sim \sum_n e^{-\beta E_n/2}|n,n\rangle.$$
If we think of this as two black holes living in disjoint spaces with the same time, we can clearly see that that this has an Einstein-Rosen (ER) bridge by looking at the Penrose diagram, and there is clearly entanglement from looking at the state $|\psi\rangle$. However, after that, they analyze the asymptotically flat two-sided black hole

[image]

I can easily see that this has an ER bridge from looking at the Penrose diagram, but they further claim, "as before the black holes are maximally entangled but
not interacting." I don't get where this comes from. How do I see that these black holes are entangled?

Comment: This is derived in section 4.8 of [arXiv:1409.1231](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1231), using the same technique that is used in section 3.3 to study the Rindler case.